# Run celery task everyday at 3:00 am in every timezone? Django

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, pytz

I need to run a task a 3:00 am everyday for multiple timezones, in the app every organization has a timezone.

```
class Organization(models.Model):

    timezone = models.IntegerField(choices=((i, i) for i in range(-12, 13)))
```

So if two organizations has different timezones the task should be executed a 3:00 am in their respective timezones i.e. not at the same time.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Those are not timezones. A timezone may have daylight savings time. It may also have a fraction of an hour, like UTC+5:30 or so. Better use Python's build-in timezones module. They are usually named "Brussels/Europe" etc.

Comment: I can not change that since the project is not only mine and there is code in it that depends on that model as it is, including the 'timezone' fields.

Comment: What if two organizations has the same timezone, does the task execute only once which is meant to process both organizations already?

Comment: Yes exactly, It would be one task per every organization in that timezone.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for this is by:

1. List all the necessary timezones (e.g. `Asia/Manila`) and their corresponding UTC offsets (e.g. `+8.0`). Here is a complete list of the [timezone names and their UTC offsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).
2. Get the equivalent in UTC of each timezone's 03:00 AM
3. Configure Celery to be based on UTC and then schedule the tasks with [celery beat](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) that will run for each timezone's 03:00 AM converted in UTC

Code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime, time, timezone
from decimal import Decimal
import pytz  # If using > Python3.9, you can try using the built-in library zoneinfo

### Step 1: Collect all the UTC offsets for all timezones

utc_offsets = set()

for tz in pytz.all_timezones:
    # If needed, filter the timezones to only the ones that are necessary, skip those that are not needed.
    dt = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(tz))

    # Decimal was used instead of the built-in float for a more accurate precision
    dt_utc_offset_seconds = Decimal(dt.utcoffset().total_seconds())
    dt_utc_offset_minutes = dt_utc_offset_seconds / Decimal('60')
    dt_utc_offset_hours = dt_utc_offset_minutes / Decimal('60')
    utc_offsets.add(dt_utc_offset_hours)

### Step 2: Get the equivalent in UTC of each timezone's 03:00 AM

TASK_HOUR_TARGET = Decimal('3')
task_hour_per_tz = set()

for utc_offset in utc_offsets:
    if utc_offset == 0:
        task_hour_as_utc_offset = TASK_HOUR_TARGET

    elif utc_offset > 0:
        task_hour_as_utc_offset = TASK_HOUR_TARGET - utc_offset

        if task_hour_as_utc_offset < 0:
            task_hour_as_utc_offset = 24 - abs(task_hour_as_utc_offset)

    elif utc_offset < 0:
        task_hour_as_utc_offset = TASK_HOUR_TARGET + abs(utc_offset)

        if task_hour_as_utc_offset >= 24:
            task_hour_as_utc_offset = task_hour_as_utc_offset - 24

    task_hour_per_tz.add((utc_offset, task_hour_as_utc_offset))

### Step 3: Schedule the execution of celery for each converted 03:00 AM of each timezone

@dataclass
class crontab:
    # For the sake of testing, here is a mocked celery.schedules.crontab
    minute: int
    hour: int

# This assumes that celery_app.conf.timezone = "UTC"
beat_schedule = {
    f"{utc_offset}": {
        'task': 'task.func',
        'schedule': crontab(
            minute=int((task_hour * Decimal('60')) % Decimal('60')),
            hour=int(task_hour),
        ),
        'kwargs': {"utc_offset": utc_offset},  # To let the task know for what timezone is the trigger for
    }
    for utc_offset, task_hour in sorted(task_hour_per_tz) # No need of the sort. It is just here so that when we print the dictionary, the order is by utc_offset.
}

for key in beat_schedule:
    print(key, beat_schedule[key])
```

Output:

```
-12 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=15), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('-12')}}
-11 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=14), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('-11')}}
-10 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=13), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('-10')}}
-9.5 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=30, hour=12), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('-9.5')}}
-9 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=12), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('-9')}}
-8 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=11), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('-8')}}
-7 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=10), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('-7')}}
-6 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=9), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('-6')}}
-5 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=8), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('-5')}}
-4 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=7), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('-4')}}
-3 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=6), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('-3')}}
-2.5 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=30, hour=5), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('-2.5')}}
-2 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=5), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('-2')}}
-1 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=4), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('-1')}}
0 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=3), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('0')}}
1 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=2), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('1')}}
2 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=1), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('2')}}
3 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=0), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('3')}}
4 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=23), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('4')}}
4.5 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=30, hour=22), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('4.5')}}
5 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=22), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('5')}}
5.5 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=30, hour=21), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('5.5')}}
5.75 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=15, hour=21), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('5.75')}}
6 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=21), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('6')}}
6.5 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=30, hour=20), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('6.5')}}
7 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=20), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('7')}}
8 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=19), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('8')}}
8.75 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=15, hour=18), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('8.75')}}
9 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=18), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('9')}}
9.5 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=30, hour=17), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('9.5')}}
10 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=17), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('10')}}
10.5 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=30, hour=16), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('10.5')}}
11 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=16), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('11')}}
12 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=15), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('12')}}
12.75 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=15, hour=14), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('12.75')}}
13 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=14), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('13')}}
14 {'task': 'task.func', 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=13), 'kwargs': {'utc_offset': Decimal('14')}}
```

As seen in the output, each timezone has its own scheduled task that will run at its equivalent of 03:00 AM in UTC (e.g. 19:00 for UTC+8.0).

- If you don't like the idea of spawning a separate scheduled task for each timezone, you might need to configure a more complex [crontab](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules) e.g. `crontab(minute=0, hour='0,1,2,3,4...')` but I don't think it is possible for some combination of timezones which would use a different minute e.g. to satisfy the converted 03:00 AM of both UTC+5.0 and UTC+5.5 which would be 22:00 and 21:30 respectively (0th and 30th minute). Though you might also just spawn a different scheduled task for a different minute setting e.g. for 0th minute, for 15th minute, for 30th minute, and for 45th minute.

Comment: Do you know how could I filter the organization timezones? Since the format used to save them in the model (As showed in the question) is not truly a timezone.

Comment: The `Organization.timezone` field is an integer right? Couldn't it be just `Organization.objects.filter(timezone=int(utc_offset))`? Here (using my solution above), `utc_offset` (which directly maps to your `Organization.timezone`) is a `Decimal` object that is an input to the task upon execution e.g. `Decimal("8")`  for the timezone of UTC+8 (or GMT+8).